# Python dict: Creating a prepared statement

Tags: python, postgresql, dictionary, prepared-statement

I'm writing a website in python where I need to use PostgreSQL as my DB.
I wanted to create a prepared statement for updating a table and I tried to create the `set` as:

```
a=dict(b=3, c='d', x=10)
keys=a.keys()
print ",".join([keys[i] + "=$" + str(i + 1) for i in range(0, len(keys))])
```

The output from this comes as

```
x=$1,c=$2,b=$3
```

which can be used to generate a prepared statement for update.

I wanted to know:

- Is there a better alternative for this?
- Is this a costly operation (should len(keys) be taken into a variable or is it an `O(1)` operation)
- Are there multiple for loops running internally? Does `a.keys()` return a deep copy of keys or is it just a reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing just fine; I use a slightly more readable version of the same code:

```
a=dict(b=3, c='d', x=10)
print ",".join(['{0}=${1}'.format(k, i) for i, k in enumerate(sorted(a))])
```

and I sorted the keys (dictionaries do not have a fixed order).

Python PostgreSQL database adapters follow the [DBAPI v2.0](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) specification, which supports using SQL parameters and give the database a chance to prepare the statement for you. However, these use a different syntax, usually one or two of the variants named in the specification.

Comment: Why the [] inside the .join()? Can't you leave it out and use a generator form?

Comment: @jterrace: you can, but `.join()` is slow when passed a generator. Use a list comprehension instead is faster.

Comment: interesting, did not know that

Comment: @Isaac: Relatively speaking. It is slow-*er*. :-) But make the number of items joined *less* and it becomes more pronounced. With only 5 or 10 items it's almost double.

Comment: I find that the common knowledge about the performance difference between _generator_ , _list_, _list comprehension_ and the various loop mechanisms is often wrong when tested against particular use cases. Your best bet is to actually profile this on your real data.

Comment: @Nisan.H: The problem with `.join()` is that it needs to loop over the items to be joined twice. Giving it a list makes that process faster. Every time. With longer lists the difference is less pronounced but you are always going to win with a list comprehension *when using `.join()`*.

Comment: Do we really need to sort the dict? Values will always correspond to their keys. Won't they? I mean name=$1, empid=$2 with values ('Martijn', 1008) should be same as empid=$1,name=$2 with values (1008, 'Martijn')

Comment: @Mayank: Provided you don't alter the `dict`, you don't need to sort. It's not clear how you are going to use these prepared statements, hence my remark about the DBAPI standard.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I did not know about `.join` looping twice over the iterable. That makes sense.